# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'breezypythongui'

Tags: python

I have created GUI program in python which converts C2F and F2C when I run my program I get an error though I imported module correctly. Can anyone please help me to solve an error

Code:

```
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame
#from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import *

class ProgDemo(EasyFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        EasyFrame.__init__(self,width="600", title = "Program")

        self.addLabel(text = "Temp",row = 1, column = 0)
        self.getinput = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0,row = 1,column = 1)

        self.addLabel(text = "Output",row = 2, column = 0)
        self.op = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0,row = 2,column = 1)


        self.grp1 = self.addRadiobuttonGroup(row = 3,column = 0)
        C_to_F = self.grp1.addRadiobutton(text = "C to F")
        F_to_C = self.grp1.addRadiobutton(text = "F to C")

        self.conBtn = self.addButton(text = "convert",row = 5, column = 0,command = self.tempc)
        self.resetBtn = self.addButton(text = "reset",row = 5, column = 1,command = self.reseti)

    def tempc(self):
        ipval = self.getinput.getNumber()
        if self.grp1.getSelectedButton()["value"] == "C to F":
            op = 9.0/5.0 * ipval + 32
        else:
            op = (ipval - 32) * 5.0/9.0
        self.op.setValue(op)

    def reseti(self):
        self.getinput.setValue(0);
        self.op.setValue(0);

def main():
    ProgDemo().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you include information about how you setup, installed, or included brezzypythongui into your project?

Comment: I just imported brezzypythongui

Comment: didn't setup anything

Comment: An error message does not need a screenshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, the module is missing and you need it.

So download and install it: http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/breezypythongui/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the module breezepythongui.py and your python code in the same folder. Not only having the folder but both modules must be in the same folder.

For example; My python code "myfirstguiproject.py" and "breezypythongui.py" are in the same folder.

I know when you extract the downloaded zip file named breezypythongui.zip, it will create a folder and in that folder there is the "breezypythongui.py" module. You need to get rid of the folder and only keep the module (breezypythongui.py).